# How to split train and test dataset to X_Train y_train and X_Test y_Test?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

So I successfully split my dataset into Train & Test in a ratio of 70:30
I used this:

```
df_glass['split'] = np.random.randn(df_glass.shape[0], 1)
msk = np.random.rand(len(df_glass)) <= 0.7
train = df_glass[msk]
test = df_glass[~msk]
print(train)
print(test)
```

Now how do I split train and test to `X_train` and `y_train` and `X_test` and `y_test`
Such that, `X` denotes the features of the database and y denotes the response?

I need to do supervised learning and apply ML modules on `X_Train` and `y_Train`.

My database looks like this:
[Database_snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/821hK.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess you may found this useful to understand..

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

#importing dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Salary_Data.csv')
x = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values

#spliting the dataset into training and test set
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, 
test_size=1/3, random_state=0)
```

Comment: Hi can you help me understand the meaning of : 
x = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values

Acc to the database my features are in first 5 columns and the last column is the response.

Comment: a Few tweaks here and there and It worked! Thanks

Comment: iloc is just basically integer-location based indexing for selection by position. my model was a simple linear regression with one independent variable and i was splitting the data into x = "independent variable" and y = "dependent variable" following the linear equation y = mx + b.

Answer (score 3):

Scikit-Learn has a convenience method for splitting pandas dataframes -

This will do the split -

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[list_of_X_cols], df['y'], test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

Comment: I am a beginner so can you explain me what should I pass through "list_of_X_cols"

Comment: the list of columns that you will treat as independant variables. These are basically a comma separated list of column names in your data

Comment: Great! Thank yo u Vivek